# Pass a list to geodjango multipolygon lookup

Tags: django, geodjango

I have a list of points like following:

```
points_list = [<Point object at 0x7f92b96103c8>, <Point object at 0x7f92b96105e8>]
```

Now I want to use this list to filter on a MultipolygonField. I can't pass this whole list to the multipolygon lookup because I get an error, `Tuple too long for lookup covers`.

Now what I have done is simply loop through the list and save the filtered multipolygon objects in a new list like:

Say `geom` below is a `multipolygon` field

```
multipolygon_list = []
for point in points_list:
    dam_obj = DAM.objects.filter(geom__contains=point).values_list('id', flat=True)
    multipolygon_list.append(dam_object)
```

Now what I want is to remove the loop above and all this is a single query. Is there a way to remove it?
Like can't I do something like below?

```
DAM.objects.filter(geom__contains=points_list)...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question as I find the solution.
So I wanted to remove the loop.

I made a union of the Points list and created a single `Multipoint` and then passed that multipoint to the lookup.

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models import Union
single_multipoint = Union(points_list)

# pass the single multipoint to the lookup.
DAM.objects.filter(geom__contains=single_multipoint)
```